# How to select and read a txt file from treeview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, selecteditem

I want to build a notes app for my first project. And I have gotten so far to create a file and put it in the tree view. I want now to be able to select the file from tree view and open it in the textbox. I can't seem to find a way to select the file.

This is my treeView, I tried to use SelecetedItemChanged

```
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Width="10" Margin="3" Source="images/drive.png"/>
                                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>

            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

and here is my C# code

```
private void FolderView_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            // get selected item path

            string fileName = FolderView.SelectedValuePath;

            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    noteText.Text = s;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have also noticed that people use different types of styles or approaches of treeview, like some are using items, children or nodes. I guess they are the same, right?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
string fileName = FolderView.SelectedValuePath;
```

Here is the documentation on [`SelectedValuePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath), it's not what you use when you're trying to get the actual selected value.

Guessing from your code, it looks like each item in the `TreeView` is just a `string`, so try this code instead:

```
string fileName = (string)FolderView.SelectedItem;
```

EDIT:

You say in your comments that `SelectedItem` is returning a `TreeViewItem`. In that case, this might work:

```
string fileName = (string)((TreeViewItem)FolderView.SelectedItem).DataContext;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. I did try that some time ago, the problem face with SelectedItem is that it returns an object value and I have not yet found how to get a path out of it. :(

Comment: @upizs I just updated the my answer. If your items are actually of type `string` then the above should work. Otherwise it will throw an exception, which you should include in the question as useful information.

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but what I get is "System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem Header:Again Items.Count:0" , not a path, I don't know what to do with this. I guess I will just try a different approach. One of my friends said to look into json that I might find a way to do it. But before that I found one video on youtube. Ill check that first.

Comment: @upizs `FolderView.SelectedItem` returns a `TreeViewItem`? In that case you can try `(string)((TreeViewItem)FolderView.SelectedItem).DataContext`

Comment: It worked! :) Nice. I used "Tag" to save the full path and used that instead of DataContext and it returned full path. Thanks a lot, you have returned my faith in my project :D 
Do you happen to know something I can read about this to make better sense?